# Sql Server Can we use multiple OR and AND conditions in the same if clause

Tags: sql-server, toad

I have used multiple OR and AND conditions in IF clause, but it is throwing error
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'OR'.

```
DECLARE @PaidAmount1 DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @PaidAmount2 DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @PaidAmount3 DECIMAL(18, 2);
DECLARE @PaidAmount4 DECIMAL(18, 2);


IF(((ISNULL(@PaidAmount1,'')) OR (@PaidAmount1='') OR (@PaidAmount1=0.00)) AND ((ISNULL(@PaidAmount2,'')) OR (@PaidAmount2='') OR (@PaidAmount2=0.00)) AND ((ISNULL(@PaidAmount3,'')) OR (@PaidAmount3='') OR (@PaidAmount3=0.00)) AND ((ISNULL(@PaidAmount4,'')) OR (@PaidAmount4='') OR (@PaidAmount4=0.00)))
BEGIN
--statements goes here
END
```

Can we use OR and AND conditions like above?

Thanks!
Shyam

Comment: `((ISNULL(@PaidAmount1,''))` is not a boolean expression

Comment: Also, Your variables are decimals, why compare them to an empty string?

Comment: use something like this ((ISNULL(@PaidAmount1,'')='') or @PaidAmount1 IS NULL

Comment: HoneyBadger and NP007 What you said is correct. Decimal is not accepting a string.

Answer (score 1):

`isnull` returns the first argument if it isn't `null` or the second argument if the first is `null`. As the error message says, it's not a `boolean` in this case. If you want to check for nullibiliy, you need to use the `is null` operator:

```
IF (((@PaidAmount1 IS NULL) OR (@PaidAmount1 = '') OR (@PaidAmount1 = 0.00)) AND 
    ((@PaidAmount2 IS NULL) OR (@PaidAmount2 = '') OR (@PaidAmount2 = 0.00)) AND 
    ((@PaidAmount3 IS NULL) OR (@PaidAmount3 = '') OR (@PaidAmount3 = 0.00)) AND 
    ((@PaidAmount4 IS NULL) OR (@PaidAmount4 = '') OR (@PaidAmount4 = 0.00)))
```

Comment: this is almost correct except for @PaidAmount1='' is not accepted since it is decimal.

Comment: This is correct condition
IF (((@PaidAmount1 IS NULL) OR (@PaidAmount1 = 0.00)) AND 
    ((@PaidAmount2 IS NULL) OR (@PaidAmount2 = 0.00)) AND 
    ((@PaidAmount3 IS NULL) OR (@PaidAmount3 = 0.00)) AND 
    ((@PaidAmount4 IS NULL) OR (@PaidAmount4 = 0.00)))